# Correlation between Entity Framework June CTP 2011 and Entity Framework 4.2?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

Is Entity Framework June CTP 2011 a version of .NET Framework to accommodate the newer Entity Framework?
Because I installed EF 4.2 and uninstalled the CTp and that broke a bunch of stuff and I had to reinstall the CTP. Also if it's showing as target framework then it's actually a .NET framework and not a pure Entity Framework?

Also isn't there a stand alone EF 4.2 installer and not just a NuGet one? Are there 4.2 EF tools?

I think these releases are making things a little confusing and breaking stuff. I am seeing some ADO.NET generators along with with 4.2 counterparts. I have spent today several hours trying to fix different Visual Studio issues and it's getting frustrating. I am not sure anymore which component has installed the new stuff I am seeing in VS. it's getting confusing and messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is confusing. ADO.NET team recently made several confusing decisions and they plan some more. One of them was to use 4.2 target for CTP 2011 and in the same time release EFv4.2 as fixed version of EFv4.1 Update 1.

In short CTP 2011 is not EFv4.2. Features from CTP 2011 will be included [in .NET 4.5 with all its pros and cons](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/10/ef-4-5-is-coming-in-the-next-net-4-5-developer-preview/). DbContext API and code first will be still separate download and it will be only available through NuGet (like EFv4.2).